# Dynamically populating table names from dropdownlist and displaying in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a web page that contains one Dropdownlist and Gridview.

Query is Dropdownlist will contains SQL Server database table list. When I select a table name from dropdownlist the Gridview needs to show entire table data and able to perform edit, update, delete, cancel action.

When I click edit Gridview need to show update and cancel buttons and it update should update dropdownlist table and also delete.

My code looks this:

**Html page:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DataGridView_Sample._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-size: x-large;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <h5 class="style1">
            Data Grid View Sample</h5>

    </div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
         <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select --" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Emp" Value="Emp"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Dept" Value="Dept"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <br />
    <br />
    <b>Grid View:</b>
    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="181px" 
        onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
        Width="518px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            &nbsp;
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**.aspx page code:**

```
namespace DataGridView_Sample
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHINY-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NRK;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select name from sys.tables order by name", con);
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
                DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "name";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "--Select--"));
            }
        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != 0)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value, con);
                con.Open();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value, con);
            con.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.EditIndex = Convert.ToInt16(e.NewEditIndex);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Please any one can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem or error you are having?

Comment: If what you're asking is how do you anticipate the columns you'll have to update (I assume not all tables have the same column names), you'll need to build the update statement on the fly. Perhaps you could store your column information in a table with 2 columns, tablename and columnname? Then build the update statement from that information?

Comment: code for GridView1_RowUpdating,GridView1_RowCancelingEdit events. It is dynamically populating data from sql table to Gridview using Dropdownlist.

Comment: yes. example, emp table may contaiin 4 columns, and dept table may contains 6 colums. so when i update the table it should update and also work cancel event for this.

Answer (score 0):

Given the above, I'd create a database table with two fields: tablename and columnname. There will be 4 rows with tablename = emp and each row will have a columnname = one of the columns from the emp table. Similarly, there will be 6 rows where tablename = dept and each row will have a columnname = one of the columns from the dept table. Then, in your GridView1_RowUpdating event, you can pull the names of the columns from the database based on the table that's been chosen in the DropDownList and update accordingly using whatever stored procedure you have in place for that table. In GridView1_RowCancelingEdit, you just need to do

```
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
```

and rebind your data (you'll need a method for that) you're done.